# Merging duplicates with consecutive sets of dates while retaining earliest and latest date

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've been searching around but cannot find a solution to the specific task I am trying to achieve.

I have a huge spreadsheet with data on stay of guests over 2 year period in a hotel I look after. Many of these guests extend their stay in which case a new reservation is created. I am trying to ascertain the real check-in and check-out dates of said guests in order to know the real number of departures we had and real average length of stay.

Essentially I am trying to find a way for excel to find duplicates based on 3 columns (room/first name/last name), assess if these have consecutive check-out = check-in date and then merge these ones by retaining earliest check-in and latest check-out.

Example below:

| Row | Room | First Name | Last Name | Check-in | Check-out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | John | Smith | 01/01/2022 | 02/01/2022 |
| 2 | 102 | Luke | Skywalker | 01/01/2022 | 05/01/2022 |
| 3 | 101 | John | Smith | 02/01/2022 | 03/01/2022 |
| 4 | 103 | John | Smith | 03/01/2022 | 04/01/2022 |
| 5 | 101 | John | Smith | 04/01/2022 | 05/01/2022 |

In the above example row 1 and 3 have same room number & names with equal check-out & check-in dates, row 1 check-out should be amended to check-out date from row 3 and row 3 should be deleted.

Row 4 should remain untouched as room number is different.

Row 5 should remain untouched as check-in in not equal to check-in in row 3.

Final result would be:

| Row | Room | First Name | Last Name | Check-in | Check-out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | John | Smith | 01/01/2022 | **03/01/2022** |
| 2 | 102 | Luke | Skywalker | 01/01/2022 | 05/01/2022 |
| 4 | 103 | John | Smith | 03/01/2022 | 04/01/2022 |
| 5 | 101 | John | Smith | 04/01/2022 | 05/01/2022 |

I assume the most elegant solution would rest in VBA and although I have an acceptable knowledge of basic functions in VBA I can't figure out how to articulate that.

I am using Excel 365.

Thanking you in advance, any suggestions you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range` or `From within sheet`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source/table in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Row", Int64.Type}, {"Room", Int64.Type}, 
        {"First Name", type text}, {"Last Name", type text}, 
        {"Check-in", type date}, {"Check-out", type date}}),

//Group by Room and names, then call custom function to merge rows if check-out = next check-in date
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Room", "First Name", "Last Name"},
        {"Stay", each fnMergeConsecutive(_),type table[Row=Int64.Type, Room=Int64.Type, First Name=text, Last Name=text, #"Check-in"=date, #"Check-out"=date]}),

//Remove unneeded columns
//Then expand the resultant sub-tables
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Room", "First Name", "Last Name"}),
    #"Expanded Stay" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Stay", 
        {"Row", "Room", "First Name", "Last Name", "Check-in", "Check-out"}),

//sort by check-in date
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Stay",{{"Check-in", Order.Ascending}, {"Room", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Add a custom function by pasting the code below into another blank query.
Rename the query: `fnMergeConsecutive`

***Custom function M Code***

```
//rename fnMergeConsecutive
(t as table) =>

let 

//if this check-in and previous check-out dates are the same, then replace this check-in with previous check-in
//then convert that list to a table
    #"Adjust Check-in Date" = List.Generate(
        ()=>[r=t{0}, idx=0],
        each [idx] < Table.RowCount(t),
        each [r= Record.TransformFields(t{[idx]+1},{"Check-in", (f)=> if f = [r][#"Check-out"] then [r][#"Check-in"] else f }),
        idx=[idx]+1],
        each [r]),
    #"Convert to Table" = Table.FromRecords(#"Adjust Check-in Date"), 

//Retain only the row with the latest check-out date for all rows with the same check-in date
    #"Return Stay Dates" = Table.Group(#"Convert to Table","Check-in",
        {"rsd", (t)=> Table.SelectRows(t, each [#"Check-out"] = List.Max(t[#"Check-out"])),
                type table[Row=Int64.Type, Room=Int64.Type, First Name=text, Last Name=text, #"Check-in"=date, #"Check-out"=date]}),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Return Stay Dates",{"Check-in"}),
    
    #"Expanded rsd" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "rsd",
        {"Row", "Room", "First Name", "Last Name", "Check-in", "Check-out"})
in
    #"Expanded rsd"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem and I've learnt a bit more about power query ^^

Answer (score 0):

*This solves the issue:*

**Sheet With Duplicates:**

[image]

---

**Sheet With Filtered Records:**

[image]

---

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
     Dim DbALLrecords, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet
     Set DbALLrecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DUPL1")
     Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DUPL2")

     DbALLrecords.Range("G1:K8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
     DuplicateRecords.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    
    End Sub
```

---

**N.B.**

- For faster use I've created Command Button, you may use this code as
  standard module.
- Code copies visible duplicates considering both Room Number as well First & Last
  Name  from Sheet DUPL1 to Sheet DUPL2.
- Adjust cell references as needed.